# 連続置換ダイアログでインポート/エクスポートができない

Tags: emeditor

EmEditor 19.9.x以降、連続置換ダイアログにTSVファイルのインポート/エクスポートボタンがなくなりました。とても重宝していた機能ですので、連続置換ダイアログに再度インポート/エクスポート機能を追加してくださるようお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

連続の一覧で右クリックして表示されるメニューから [インポート]、[エクスポート] を選択していただけます。

[image: 連続置換ダイアログ]

Comment: 見落としていました。お教えいただきありがとうございます。